# Lua concate all table values

Tags: lua, tostring, lua-table

I want to override the __tostring meta method for a table
So I use the following code

```
st=""
for key, value in pairs(tbl)
    do
      st=st.."  "..key.." = "..value.."\n" --error here
    end
```

but this gives me error `attempt to concatenate local 'value'`, can someone tell me why?

Comment: What is `tbl`? Provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only concatenate strings or numbers (which Lua converts to a string).

You obviously have an element in your table that is neither a string nor a number.
Hence the concat operator `..` reports an error.

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.6